# angularJS with laravel partial template javascript file issue in public folder

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-routing

I have a partial template file in templates folder, that includes

languages

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="controllers/languagesController.js"></script>
<div ng-controller="languagesController">

{{name}}    

</div>
```

languagesController

```
hrmsApp.controller("languagesController",function($scope){

         $scope.name = "test";

});
```

but the controller inside this function is not recognized by the app file.

app.js

```
var hrmsApp = angular.module("hrmsApp",['ui.router','ngSanitize','ngResource']);

hrmsApp.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $controllerProvider) {

$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');

hrmsApp.registerCtrl = $controllerProvider.register;

$stateProvider
              .state("login",{
                    url         :  "/",
                    templateUrl :  "/templates/login.php"
              })

              .state("dashboard", {
                    url         : "/dashboard",
                    views       : {

                                    ''                  :   {templateUrl : "/templates/dashboard.php"},

                                    'navMenu@dashboard' :   {templateUrl :  "/templates/menu.php"}
                    }
              })

              .state("languages", {
                    url         : "/languages",
                    views       : {
                    '': {templateUrl : "/templates/languages.php",
                         controller  : "languagesController"
                        },
                    'navMenu@languages' : {templateUrl  :   "/templates/menu.php"}
                    }

              })

              .state("logout", {
                    url         :   "/logout",
                    controller  :   "logout"
              })
});
```

The "`languagesController`" function inside the `languagesController.js` is not recognized and the following error occurs.

```
"Error: [ng:areq] Argument 'languagesController' is not a function"
```

But when I put the same controller function inside `app.js` file the function is recognized and also the script file inside partial template. I want to keep all controller file in separate directory for easy accessibility and maintenance. But placing in separate file and calling the file throws error. Please suggest a way for doing this, so that my controllers should be in separate directory and the call to controller file should be in partial template file.

Comment: May you check within the console if controllers/languagesController.js is loading or not?

Comment: languagescontroller.js file is loading successfully. And the response is also successful. But the controller function is not recognized. Languages.php file is loaded first and then the languagesController.js file.